# I want to load images withen the folder and want to get all images in base64 in my js for future use

Tags: javascript, filereader

i am facing the issue i always get the last image in my image array due to kind of Filereader library function onloadend.
how can i get base64 for all images in my folder.

```
<input id="file-input" multiple webkitdirectory type="file" />
var input = document.getElementById('file-input');
var file_names = "";
var entries_length = 0;
var entries_count = 0;
var image = new Array();   
var obj = {};
var j = 0;
input.onchange = function(e) {
        var files = e.target.files; // FileList
        entries_length = files.length;
        console.log(files);

        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; ++i){
            console.log("i:"+i);
            entries_count = entries_count + 1;
            //console.debug(files[i].webkitRelativePath);
            if(files[i].type=="image/jpeg")
            {

                var string = files[i].webkitRelativePath;
                var name = string.split("/")[3]; //this is because my image in 3rd dir in the folder
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function() {

                        obj.name = string.split("/")[3];
                        obj.image = reader.result;
                        image[j] = obj;
                        j = j+1;

                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);

            }

        }
       console.log(image);
    }
```

Comment: _"i always get the last image in my image array due to"_ ... `obj` being a global variable referring to an object, yes. Make it a local variable, and assign it a new empty object each time before you assign the property values.

Comment: _"var input = document.getElementById('file-input'){"_ - that doesn't look like valid JS, with the `{` at the end ...

Comment: This is not a issue but i tried to do, issue still there.

Comment: can you give a try? @CBroe

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you need dataURI versions ? You'd be really better with the lighter and synchronous URL.createObjectURL if all you need is to display these files ; and if what you want is to upload it on a server, then you'd be really better sending it as an octet-stream (send directly the Blobs) rather than a dataURI version. Actually there are only a very limited set of cases where you need a dataURI version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the asynchronous loading of files. You iterate over the array and set the `onloadend` handler for the reader each time, then start loading by calling `readAsDataURL`.

One problem is that by the time your first image loads, it is possible the `for` loop has completed, and `i` is already at the last index of the array.

At this point, obtaining the path from `files[i].webkitRelativePath` will give you the last filename, and not the one you are expecting.

Check the [example for readAsDataURL on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) to see one possible solution - each load is performed in a separate function, which preserves its scope, along with `file.name`. Do not be put off by the construction they are using: `[].forEach.call(files, readAndPreview)`. This is a way to map over the files, which are a FileList and not a regular array (so the list does not have a forEach method of its own).

So, it should be sufficient to wrap the loading logic in a function which takes the file object as a parameter:

```
var images = [];

function loadFile(f) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function () {
        images.push({
            name : f.name, // use whatever naming magic you prefer here
            image : reader.result
        });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}

for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    loadFile(files[i]);
}
```

Each call of the function 'remembers' the file object it was called with, and prevents the filename from getting messed up. If you are interested, [read up on closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

This also has the nice effect of isolating your reader objects, because I have a sneaking suspicion that, although you create a new 'local' reader each iteration, javascript scoping rules are weird and readers could also be interfering with each other (what happens if one reader is loading, but in the same scope you create a new reader with the same variable name? Not sure).

Now, you do not know how long it would take for all images to be loaded, so if you want to take an action right after that, you would have to perform a check each time an `onloadend` gets called. This is the essence of asynchronous behavior.

As an aside, I should note that it is pointless to manually keep track of the last index of `images`, which is `j`. You should just use `images.push({ name: "bla", image: "base64..." })`. Keeping indices manually opens up possibilities for bugs.

Comment: I have give a try on it problem is now some how resolve but on problem still there

Comment: What problem is still there, could you clarify?